# Linq Expression throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: .net, linq, nhibernate, lambda, linq-expressions

I am building an `Expression` which should represent an `Equals` comparison of a property and a constant of type `Nullable<long>`. In other words, compiling the expression should return a lambda similar to `x => (x.Id == value)`, where both `Id` and `value` are of type `long?`.

This is the code:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetNullableIdEqualsQuery(long? value)
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    var idProperty = type.GetProperty("Id");
    var xParam = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");

    var block = Expression.Block(
        typeof(bool),
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(xParam, idProperty),
            Expression.Constant(value, typeof(long?)))
        );

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(block, xParam);
}
```

But when used in a query, it fails with an `InvalidOperationException`:

> System.InvalidOperationException: variable `'x'` of type `'SomeEntity'` referenced from scope `''`, but it is not defined.

What am I doing wrong?

**[Edit]**

Thanks to @MarcGravell's answer, I've fixed the code. I am presuming that something was broken in the NHibernate's LINQ provider, but right now I don't have the time to investigate further.

If anyone needs a generic version which will (well, should) work for any property type, here it is:

```
public static Expression<Func<Tobj, bool>> GetEqualsQuery<Tobj, Tprop>(Tprop value, string propertyName)
{
    var type = typeof(Tobj);
    var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
    var propertyType = property.PropertyType;
    if (propertyType != typeof(Tprop))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Property type ({0}) does not match the value type ({1})"
            .FormatWith(propertyType, typeof(Tprop)));

    var xParam = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");

    var body = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(xParam, property),
        Expression.Constant(value, propertyType)
    );

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Tobj, bool>>(body, xParam);
}
```

Test (for the lambda-compiled version only):

```
[TestClass]
public class ExpressionHelperTest
{
    class Test
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetEqualsQueryWorksForSimpleTypes()
    {
        // create a query for the lambda x => x.Id == 5
        var lambda = ExpressionHelper
            .GetEqualsQuery<Test, long>(5, "Id")
            .Compile();

        Assert.IsTrue(lambda(new Test() { Id = 5 }));
        Assert.IsFalse(lambda(new Test() { Id = 8 }));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the code in your example works fine; is it possible that in the *real* code you aren't supplying the parameter to the expression (in the `Lambda<T>` call), or perhaps you are re-writing the expression without substituting the parameters?

Comment: @Marc: actually, I was passing it to NHibernate (not exactly the latest build), so it might be possible that `null` check is not implemented properly in their provider (as you mentioned below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't use `Expression.Block`:

```
    var body = Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(xParam, idProperty),
            Expression.Constant(value, typeof(long?)));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, xParam);
```

Also note that some providers don't correctly implement the above when the value is `null`. If you need to look for `null` matches, you might need to special-case that scenario and explicitly check `HasValue`:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetNullableIdEqualsQuery<T>(long? value)
{
    var xParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    Expression body;
    if (value == null)
    {
        body = Expression.Not(
            Expression.Property(
                Expression.Property(xParam, "Id"),
                "HasValue"));
    }
    else
    {
        body = Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(xParam, "Id"),
            Expression.Constant(value, typeof(long?)));
    }
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, xParam);
}
```